# How to cast a derived table to the composite type that corresponds to the original table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I build a derived table so that I know that the structure of the derived table is identical to the original table:

```
create table people_derived as
select * from people where <some_predicate>;
```

Is it possible to cast records of the derived table (people_derived) to the composite type based on the original table (people) (once again I know the structures match)? I want this:

```
select p::"people" from people_derived p;
```

The above query gives me the following error:
    ERROR:  42846: cannot cast type people_derived to people

The reason is that I have a function foo that takes "people"[] as parameter but I want to apply it to the reduced set of people. In my real application it is a series of intermediate queries but I know that I keep the structure of the original table. The only solution that I know is as follows:

```
create table people_derived as
select *, p as p from people p where <some_predicate>;
select foo(array_agg(p)) from people_derived p;
```

But I don't like this solution because it doubles the size of table people_derived and I work with huge tables (hundred columns, 100M records).

Answer (score 0):

I believe such casts are only allowed directly if you have a formal inheritance relationship between the two tables:

```
ALTER TABLE people_derived INHERIT people;
```

However, this would mean that `SELECT * FROM people` also returns the contents of `people_derived`, which is likely not what you want (though you could avoid this using `SELECT * FROM ONLY people`).

The simplest workaround I can think of, provided that the column types and column order are identical, is to cast to `text` and back again:

```
SELECT p::text::people FROM people_derived p;
```

Somewhat nicer would be to cast via the generic `record` pseudotype, rather than `text`, but Postgres appears to ignore such casts in this context. You can coerce it to a `record` in a slightly more roundabout way, using a derived table:

```
SELECT t::people FROM (SELECT * FROM people_derived) t
```